# Problem at installing roboearth stack

Tags: ros-fuerte, roboearth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i had some issues in my os so i had to uninstall it and reinstall ubuntu 12.04 and fuerte again but when i was trying to install roboearth stack from this tutorial [RoboEarth Stack](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roboearth_stack)

i got this :-

```
wafaay@wafaay:~$ rosinstall ~/ros /opt/ros/fuerte 'http://www.ros.org/wiki/roboearth?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=roboearth.rosinstall'

> ERROR in config: Is not a local file,
> nor able to download as a URL

[http://www.ros.org/wiki/roboearth?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=roboearth.rosinstall]: 

urlopen error [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

what that error suppose to mean ?.. is this link out of date or something ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56407/problem-at-installing-roboearth-stack/) by [Wafaay](https://answers.ros.org/users/3703/wafaay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2013-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Oops, sorry. We recently moved the wiki page and forgot to adjust the install instruction. Try it again with `rosinstall ~/ros /opt/ros/fuerte 'http://www.ros.org/wiki/roboearth_stack?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=roboearth.rosinstall'`

---

Originally posted by [ddimarco](https://answers.ros.org/users/1073/ddimarco/) with karma: 916 on 2013-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1